# makefile undefined references to functions that are defined

Tags: c++, makefile

When trying to compile a project I have made I am getting a

undefined reference to `Timers::NextTimerTime(timeval*)'

which is a method I have defined in timers.cc, but am using in client.cpp. I have included the correct header file, but it can not find the definition in the timers.cc file.

```
CXX       =      g++
CPPFLAGS  =     -I. -g -Wall -fno-inline
FLAGS     =     ${CPPFLAGS} ${AC_DEFS}

all: client

default:
    all

tools.o: tools.cc tools.hh
    $(CXX) $(FLAGS) -c tools.cc

timers.o: timers.cc timers.hh
    $(CXX) $(FLAGS) -c timers.cc


client.o: client.cpp client.h
    $(CXX) $(FLAGS) -c client.cpp 


client:  client.o timers.o tools.o  
    $(CXX) $(FLAGS) client.o -o client

clean:
    rm -f client *.o
```

This code compiles in eclipse, but I can not generate a make file for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(CXX) $(FLAGS) client.o -o client
```

You're only linking with the `client.o` file, not the other object files.

Comment: And that's why I should post my question on here rather than beating my head against the wall. Works great, thanks, I'll accept when I can.